# DVD program and flash not working right on MacBook Pro?

Tags: macos, flash, posix, filenames

I have a DVD that came with a school book the book is called CompTIA A+ Guide to Managing and Maintaining Your PC. It came with a DVD that has some interactive labs on it that work thru html files and flash player. There is a master HTML file on the disk that runs the whole thing. After everything is activated with numbers and all that jazz you have a screen that lists all the labs you can do. You have to set Flash up to allow access to a folder on the DVD that holds the labs HTML files. I have this working on my PC thru Firefox and Internet Explore. I want to be able to do this on my MacBook pro. So far i can't get it to work on Safari or Firefox or Opera on my Mac. I have set up flash the same way and if i use Finder to go directly to the chapter1_lab1.html file it works. But when i try and do it by access the master HTML file and clicking on one of the labs listed it doesn't work. Safari sits on a blank screen and Firefox gives me this error.

File not found
Firefox can't find the file at file///Volumes/LabConnection/Labs/2207012/Chapter1_Lab1/chapter1_lab1.html

What i have figured out is that on the DVD the files are listed with capitals (Chapter1_Lab1 not chapter1_lab1) If i enter this part into the address bar of Firefox ( file///Volumes/LabConnection/Labs/2207012/Chapter1_Lab1/chapter1_lab1.html) i get the same error if i change the c and l to Capitals it plays the lab. Hope this is understandable. What do i need to do to make it read the file since the master is telling to look for lower case files and for some reason my Mac won't recognize it has the same file with the upper case letters.

Answer (score 0):

Yes - the problem has to do with the casing - your DVD is broken, and will work, as it is, only on Windows. That is because Windows ignores filename casing.

You can get it to work if you copy the  files to a folder in your computer and create copies (or better yet, symbolic links if OS X will let you) of all files therein with a lowercase name.

If you want it to run from a DVD, you have to create a new DVD with two versions of each file that needs both naming schemes.

Comment: What exactly are symbolic links

Comment: A mechanism that allows one to attribute multiple names to the same file - but no need to bother  - creating copies with different casing in the names will work just the same